# Computing the pro-solvable closure of a finitely generated subgroup of a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, profinite-groups, automata-theory

The *pro-solvable topology* on a group $G$ is the unique group topology such that the set of normal subgroups $N\lhd G$ with $G/N$ a finite solvable group is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the identity.

Let $F$ be a finitely generated free group.  Ribes and Zalesskii proved that the pro-solvable closure $\overline H$ of finitely generated subgroup $H$ is also finitely generated (and in fact, the rank of $\overline H$ is at most the rank of $H$).

> > **Question.**  Let $H$ be a finitely generated subgroup of a finitely generated free group $F$. Is there an algorithm to compute a basis (or equivalently a generating set) for the pro-solvable closure $\overline H$ given as input a generating set for $H$?

I have a number of remarks.  First of all this is a well-known *open* problem to people working in finite semigroup theory and the algebraic theory of automata and it has a number of applications to these fields.  However, I am not sure that this question is very well known to group theorists, who would be best equipped to solve it.

**What is known.**

This problem is Turing equivalent to each of the following problems.

1. Deciding if a finitely generated subgroup of a finitely generated free group is dense in the pro-solvable topology.
2. Deciding if a finitely generated subgroup of a finitely generated free group is closed in the pro-solvable topology.
3. Deciding if a graph immersion over a wedge of circles can be extended to a finite-sheeted covering such that the permutation group obtained by making the monodromy action faithful is solvable.
4. Given a finite monoid $M$, deciding if there exists a finite solvable group $G$ and a submonoid $N$ of the power monoid $P(G)$ such that $M$ is a quotient of $N$. (OK, I don't expect anybody to solve this problem using this characterization, but...)

**Related results.**

- If $p$ is prime, then Ribes and Zalesskii provided an algorithm for
  computing a basis for the pro-$p$ closure of a finitely generated subgroup of a free group.
- Margolis, Sapir and Weil showed the pro-$p$ closure can be computed in polynomial time (I think a quintic bound was given).
- Margolis, Sapir and Weil showed that a basis for the pro-nilpotent closure of a finitely generated subgroup of a free group can be computed and also solved 1--3 for the nilpotent case (they are not *a priori* equivalent because nilpotent groups are not closed under extension).

Comment: This is a very nice problem!

Comment: The tag "open problem" would be relevant and should come first.

Comment: @J.-E. Pin, there is a max of 5 tags and I felt the others are more important. The question says in italics this is an open problem. The tags are mostly for searching and filtering nowadays so I felt open-problem is less useful than the others.